# Correct way of adding taxonomy to a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Just something I´ve been wondering for a while:

The Codex shows us two ways of attaching a Taxonomy to a Custom Post Type:

1. Using the `taxonomies` argument in the `register_post_type` function
2. Using the `object_type` variable in the `register_taxonomy` function

Should we use both methods, or is one enough? And do they give the same result?

Comment: Please post your "Update" as an **answer**, rather than as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests and it seems that we can use either one as long as the taxonomy or post type has been registered earlier in the script.